# Redux ways to share data and actions between reducers

Tags: javascript, redux

I am working on a music application that is split between several features:

- `library`: displays the available content and allows the user to browse artists and albums, and play one or a few tracks. The state looks like this:

  library {
    tracksById: {...}
    albumsById: {...}
    artistsById: {...}
    albums: []
    artists: []
  }
- `player`: the part that plays the music. Just contains an array of all tracks to be played. Also shows a list of the tracks to be played

and etc; The problem is that I would like to share `tracksById`, `albumsById` and `artistsById` between all features, because each album has an artist property, but this property is just an id, so if I want to display the artist name near the track name in the playlist, I need to fetch the artist, and put it in my store. I could simply connect them both like this:

```
@connect(createStructuredSelector({
  player: (state) => state.player,
  library: (state:) => state.library
}), (dispatch) => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
}))
```

And then in my playlist view:

```
<div className="artist-name">{this.library.artistsById[track.artist].name}</div>
```

However this increases coupling between features and I find that it defeats the very purposes of multiple reducers.

Another way would be to create a new feature `content`, which would only contain the actions and byId properties needed with the most minimal reducer possible and this one would be shared by other features. However, this means I have to add a new prop to every component `content`, and I need to add the actions.

I could also create a service, or even maybe a function that would take a a reducer and actions object, and add a logic to make it able to fetch artists, albums and tracks and save them in the store. I really like this idea since it decreases coupling, however, it means duplicated data in my state, which means more memory used.

**I am not looking for the best way, just wondering if there is any other and what are the pros and cons of each method**

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I don't fully understand your question, but I'll share some thoughts. Are you trying to avoid duplicate queries or duplicated state data?

### Objects are fast dictionaries

This bit of duplication:

`{this.library.artistsById[track.artist].name}`

becomes unnecessary if `library.artists` is an object instead of an array. Assume 1 and 2 are artist IDs, `artists` would use the artist ids as keys in the object:

```
{
   1: {name: 'Bob Marley', ...etc},
   2: {name: 'Damien Marley', ...etc}
}
```

Which lets you get artist info from `library.artists` using only the id:

`{this.library.artists[track.artistId].name}`

### Use selector functions

But what you really want is `getArtistById(state, artistId){}`, a selector function in your reducer code file. That lets you rearrange the state any time and none of your view components will be affected. If `artists` is an object with the keys being artist IDs, the implementation could look like this:

```
getArtistById(state, artistId){
    return state.library.artists[artistId]
}
```

I agree with your observation that accessing `library.artistsById[track.artist].name` adds unnecessary coupling. I would never put code that knows about high-level state shape into a view component.
For your example playlist view with a list of artists, each item in the playlist view would be its own tiny component. The container would look like this:

```
import { getArtistById } from '../reducers/root-reducer'
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   const artist = getArtistById(state.library)
   return { artistName: artist ? artist.name : '' }
}
...
```

The tiny view component would look something like:

```
render() { 
    const {artistName} = this.props
    return <div className="artist-name">{artistName}</div> 
}
```

### Premature optimization?

You might be prematurely optimizing. Even if you keep `artists` and `albums` as arrays, your selector function can search through the array for the ID. A function to get each of those by id from a state that only contains `{ artists: [], albums: [], tracks:[] }` should be very fast until the library got pretty huge.